# Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : 
  Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; 
  Value='<null>' BindingExpression:Path=Attributes[AssetSL]; 
  DataItem='DataBinding' (HashCode=4074007); 
  target element is 'RegionSSIn' (Name='rssi'); 
  target property is 'AService' (type 'SLG')
```

What that exception means ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just means what is said in your output: your binding produces a value not accepted by the control.

The property **AService**, in element **RegionSSln** is bound to a bad value. You might try using a converter to have an appropriate value.

As an example, the same problem would happen if you try for example to bind a `Visibility` to an `Integer`: it will produce the same error: the control is waiting for an object of type `Visibility`, and has something else instead